# python flask-restful deployment in google cloud engine

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, flask-restful

I'm deploying a Python application into GAE for the first time, which is using Flask-restful as REST server, and i can't get the concept of how to configure the deployment properly.

I'm trying with the minimal flask-restful application example `minimal.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

And i've configured the deployment `app.yaml` file in the following way, where the network section is trying to give access to the default 5000 port of flask-restful:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: python minimal.py

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

network:
  instance_tag: instance-1
  name: default
  forwarded_ports:
    - 5000
```

The name *default* is the only network configured in my VPC.

The deployment instruction was the following, in order to remove previous trials I did:

```
gcloud app deploy --promote --stop-previous-version
```

So, when I try with curl to post, i receive a **502** error, which i can see in my server also.

I'm missing a step somewhere... probably in the VPC network or in the app.yaml configuration, but i'm lost at this point...

Any help will be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your configuration of `yaml`.

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT minimal:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Althought I had to figure out that gunicorn has to be anually added to `requirements.txt` file in order to make it work. The regular `pip freeze > requirements.txt` wouldn't be sufficient, of course.